# Android загрузка файл с Vk.com

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Вот такой вопрос, в чем мб проблема, когда загружаю файл с стороннего сайта ( любого ), то без проблем качает ( пробовал и видео и картинки и музыку ), когда качаю файл с vk , то файл не качается ( файл создается, но с размером нулевым ( 0 байт ))
вот пример ссылки по которой качал из vk 
    url = "http://cs5473.vkontakte.ru/u161502041/audio/dbe0fce4c479.mp3";

а вот пример ссылки по которой качал с стороннего сайта ( с него все ок скачалось )
    url = "http://poiskm.ru/index.php/get/strack/8b97eb/57a198/f?qmd5l=b2d32ca273ffd1c7a5737a676413b1c2&download.mp3";

если поможет, вот LogCat когда качаю с Vk:

```
 09-30 12:45:27.884: D/dalvikvm(8985): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 285K, 18% free 4282K/5187K, paused 20ms
09-30 12:45:27.914: D/dalvikvm(8985): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 260K, 18% free 4434K/5379K, paused 20ms
09-30 12:45:27.944: D/HardwareRenderer(8985): Disabling v-sync
09-30 12:45:27.984: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(8985): SetSwapInterval() interval: 0 not set
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):           java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://cs5839.vkontakte.ru/u17402732/audio/cbfa077fcbb7.mp3
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at com.example.jervk.MainActivity$DownloadVkTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:480)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at com.example.jervk.MainActivity$DownloadVkTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at com.example.jervk.MainActivity$DownloadVkTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:466)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at com.example.jervk.MainActivity$DownloadVkTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-30 12:45:28.224: W/System.err(8985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-30 12:45:28.234: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-30 12:45:28.234: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-30 12:45:28.234: W/System.err(8985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-30 12:45:28.234: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-30 12:45:28.234: W/System.err(8985):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-30 12:45:28.234: W/System.err(8985):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-30 12:45:28.274: D/HardwareRenderer(8985): Disabling v-sync
09-30 12:45:28.284: D/OpenGLRenderer(8985): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-30 12:45:28.374: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(8985): SetSwapInterval() interval: 0 not set

а вот LogCat когда с стороннего сайта:
    09-30 13:10:23.834: D/dalvikvm(9560): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 277K, 17% free 4254K/5123K, paused 20ms
09-30 13:10:23.874: D/dalvikvm(9560): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 209K, 19% free 4376K/5379K, paused 20ms
09-30 13:10:23.904: D/HardwareRenderer(9560): Disabling v-sync
09-30 13:10:23.934: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(9560): SetSwapInterval() interval: 0 not set
09-30 13:10:24.194: D/Error....(9560): java.net.ProtocolException: HEAD does not support writing
09-30 13:10:24.264: W/System.err(9560): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 2
09-30 13:10:24.264: W/System.err(9560):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-30 13:10:24.264: W/System.err(9560):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-30 13:10:24.264: W/System.err(9560):     at com.example.jervk.MainActivity$DownloadVkTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:474)
09-30 13:10:24.264: W/System.err(9560):     at com.example.jervk.MainActivity$DownloadVkTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-30 13:10:24.264: W/System.err(9560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-30 13:10:24.274: W/System.err(9560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-30 13:10:24.274: W/System.err(9560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-30 13:10:24.274: W/System.err(9560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-30 13:10:24.274: W/System.err(9560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-30 13:10:24.274: W/System.err(9560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-30 13:10:24.274: W/System.err(9560):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-30 13:10:24.304: D/HardwareRenderer(9560): Disabling v-sync
09-30 13:10:24.304: D/OpenGLRenderer(9560): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-30 13:10:24.354: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(9560): SetSwapInterval() interval: 0 not set
```

p.s. заранее спасибо

Comment: возможно прав нету..

Comment: может потому, что файла нет - "java.io.FileNotFoundException"

Comment: доступ к vk получен, в том и дело.

Comment: иначе бы я не мог использовать методы ихние ( а я через них получаю название песни и урл )

Comment: KoVadim не могли бы поподробнее, просто дело в том что я с другого сайта без проблем загружаю и не понимаю откуда может возникнуть  Exception ( p.s. с браузера по этой ссылке все ок грузит )

Comment: есть у кого-нибудь какие-нибудь идеи ?